# Print Valid words with _ in between them

Tags: sed, awk, grep, cpu-word, concatenation

I have done my research, but not able to find the solution to my problem.
I am trying to extract all valid words(Starting with a letter) in a string and concatenate them with underscore("_"). I am looking for solution with awk, sed or grep, etc.

Something like:

```
echo "The string under consideration" | (awk/grep/sed) (pattern match)
```

**Example 1**

Input:

```
1.2.3::L2 Traffic-house seen during ABCD from 2.2.4/5.2.3a to 1.2.3.X11
```

Desired output:

```
L2_Traffic_house_seen_during_ABCD_from
```

**Example 2**

Input:

```
XYZ-2-VRECYY_FAIL: Verify failed - Client 0x880016, Reason: Object exi
```

Desired Output:

```
XYZ_VRECYY_FAIL_Verify_failed_Client_Reason_Object_exi
```

**Example 3**

Input:

```
ABCMGR-2-SERVICE_CRASHED: Service "abcmgr" (PID 7582) during UPGRADE
```

Desired Output:

```
ABCMGR_SERVICE_CRASHED_Service_abcmgr_PID_during_UPGRADE
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: In first example, why last `to` word is not included? And why is included `L2` but not `X11`?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]/ /g;s/\<[[:alpha:]]/\n&/g;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/ [^\n]*//g;y/\n/_/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` one-liner. It searches any alphabetic character followed by any number of word characters enclosed in word boundaries. Use the `/g` flag to try several matches for each line.

Content of `infile`:

```
1.2.3::L2 Traffic-house seen during ABCD from 2.2.4/5.2.3a to 1.2.3.X11
XYZ-2-VRECYY_FAIL: Verify failed - Client 0x880016, Reason: Object exi
ABCMGR-2-SERVICE_CRASHED: Service "abcmgr" (PID 7582) during UPGRADE
```

`Perl` command:

```
perl -ne 'printf qq|%s\n|, join qq|_|, (m/\b([[:alpha:]]\w*)\b/g)' infile
```

Output:

```
L2_Traffic_house_seen_during_ABCD_from_to_X11
XYZ_VRECYY_FAIL_Verify_failed_Client_Reason_Object_exi
ABCMGR_SERVICE_CRASHED_Service_abcmgr_PID_during_UPGRADE
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`, with the contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[^[:alnum:]_]"
}

{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i !~ /^[0-9]/ && $i != "") {
            if (i < NF) {
                printf "%s_", $i
            }
            else {
                print $i
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Alternatively, here is the one liner:

```
awk -F "[^[:alnum:]_]" '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i !~ /^[0-9]/ && $i != "") { if (i < NF) printf "%s_", $i; else print $i; } } }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
L2_Traffic_house_seen_during_ABCD_from_to_X11
XYZ_VRECYY_FAIL_Verify_failed_Client_Reason_Object_exi
ABCMGR_SERVICE_CRASHED_Service_abcmgr_PID_during_UPGRADE
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires some tuning and I think one needs gawk to have regexp as "record separator"
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html#Records
    gawk -v ORS='_' -v RS='[-: \"()]' '/^[a-zA-Z]/' file.dat